# How to used aligned environment and enable equation number

Tags: numbering, align, amsmath

How is it possible to use the aligned environment and enable equation numbering for both equations in the example below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\left.\begin{aligned}
a&=b\\
b&=c
\end{aligned}\right\}
\quad \forall i \in R
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

http://sciencesoft.at/lpng/586c8fd7d3db8442702cb16915124839d117e1c.png&size=100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{empheq}
\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[right=\empheqrbrace\quad\forall i \in R]{align}
  a&=b\\
  b&=c
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

Side note: `memoir` is not relevant here, it is just the default in my editor.

[image]